# Is there benefit to blocking hack bots on a static website?

Tags: apache, bots, websecurity

Every day bots try to look for ways into my website by requesting files with known vulnerabilities (e.g., "/FCKeditor/_whatsnew").  I don't have any such files because my site is static and I don't use any plugins or off-the-shelf software.  I'm irked by others trying to exploit my site so I thought I could write a script to scan the log files and then ban any IP in .htaccess which requests such phantom files.  (I can't add to the apache2.conf / http.conf file because my webhost overwrites any changes I make to that file.)  However, I don't know if banning the offenders is really any better than just letting them get the 404.  Adding a gazillion banned IPs means the server has to parse that list for each and every request by legitimate users, while not banning means that the bot just gets a 404 for their request and no payoff, and it doesn't take the server any more time to return a 404 than to return a 403-Forbidden.  But maybe I'm missing something and there's some benefit to banning the offending bots instead of just letting them get the 404.  Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to ban malicious requests, then don't do that using apache itself, but use `fail2ban`. That allows to block requesting addresses inside the systems firewall, so that apache does not even get further requests from those addresses. But I doubt that this is really worth the effort for exactly the reasons you yourself point out: the attempts will fail anyway. The only motivation for such effort would be if you run into real issues like performance problems due to the sheep number of attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Those bots are generally looking for 3rd party software (like CKEditor as you've noted in the question).
When a bot finds such software, it attempts attacks that this software is known to be vulnerable to.

But you might also see bots looking for something like `../../etc/passwd`. These scanners aren't looking for 3rd-party software, but for improperly configured permissions.

It's usually a doomed effort to try and do your own web security, so if your website is important enough and if you can afford it, get a WAF service (AWS has one) and/or a bot protection solution.

Otherwise, make sure your permissions are configured correctly, and be sure to revisit your security investment if you start to use 3rd-party software or if the value of your website's security changes.